# Dagger2 create duplicate instance of interface in Module

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I use dagger-android in my app with @ContributesAndroidInjector annotation.

```java
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBuilder {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = BleDevicesModule.class)
    abstract BleDevicesActivity bindBleDevicesActivity();
}
```

```
@Module
class BleDevicesModule {

...

@Provides
    fun provideBleObserver(bleRepository: IBluetoothRepository): IObservableUseCase<List<Device>> {
        return GetAllAvailableBleDevicesUseCase(bleRepository)
    }

    @Provides
    fun providePairDeviceUseCase(bleRepository: IBluetoothRepository): ISingleUseCaseWithParameter<Device, Boolean> {
        return ConnectDeviceUseCase(bleRepository)
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideBleRepository(bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager, context: Context,
                                      authorBleScanner: AuthorBleScanner, authProvider: IAuthProvider): IBluetoothRepository {
        return BluetoothRepository(bluetoothManager, context, authorBleScanner, authProvider)
    }
}
```

I understand that I have 2 Use Cases being created that use the dependency of the `IBluetoothRepository;` so the `provideBleRepository()` method is called twice, and each time a new BluetoothRepository object is created with all it's dependencies. How to make the repository object a singleton? As a silly solution I use variable inside BleDevicesModule, init and return it from `provideBleRepository()` but I think there must be easier way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `@Singleton`

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideBleRepository(bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager, context: Context,
                                  authorBleScanner: AuthorBleScanner, authProvider: IAuthProvider): IBluetoothRepository {
    return BluetoothRepository(bluetoothManager, context, authorBleScanner, authProvider)
```

For more information you can read this documentation : [Custom-scopes](http://frogermcs.github.io/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-custom-scopes/)

Or another option could be add the `@Singleton` annotation to your `BluetoothRepository` and then instead of returning a new object on `privodeBleRepository` you just get it from parameter.

Comment: I tried this and get error: 

`[Dagger/IncompatiblyScopedBindings] ....ActivityBuilder_BindBleDevicesActivity.BleDevicesActivitySubcomponent (unscoped) may not reference scoped bindings`

Comment: Can you just add @Singleton below the @Module? And then you have all Singleton?

Comment: I figured it out : 1. created custom scope ( assume it will be BleActivityScope). 2. Mark method with it  `@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = BleDevicesModule.class)

    @BleActivityScope

    abstract BleDevicesActivity bindBleDevicesActivity();` 3. Mark  method for repository in module `@Provides
@BleActivityScope
fun provideBleRepository(bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager, context: Context,
                                  authorBleScanner: AuthorBleScanner, authProvider: IAuthProvider): IBluetoothRepository `
Thanks!